# Do there exist any languages that use inflection to create questions?

Tags: list-of-languages, inflection, questions

In most (or all?) of Germanic languages questions are created by inversion. E.g.:

> "I am here." -> "Am I here?"

As far as I know most of Slavic languages do it simply by adding a word before the sentence. Something like:

> "I am here." -> "If I am here?"

Are there any other "methods" of creating a question? I'm especially interested if there exist languages that use inflection in order to do it? Something like:

> "I am here." -> "I is here?"

Comment: By "conjugation", do you mean a bound affix on a verb (and not a clitic)? Do you mean all questions, or would it suffice if only polar or wh-questions do this?

Comment: @user6726 An affix (or a complete change of a word), although If u know an example of a clitic, I would also be happy to know about this. Polar questions would be satisfying, but the more general the better.

Comment: The word in the Slavic languages that you alluded to is in fact a (Wackernagel) clitic.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are saying about Romance languages?

Comment: Finnish uses the suffix _-ko/-kö_ on theverb to form a question, IIRC. Japanese uses a final particle _ka_.

Comment: Turkish has a morpheme mı/mu/mi/mü which is used to form interrogatives.

Comment: @fdb Seems like my poor knowledge of Spanish and Latin needed some rehearsal. Looks like in case of Romance languages it's only the accent. Sorry about that. I've edited the question to mention only Slavic ones in this section.

Comment: Latin uses *-ne* as a question marking particle.

Comment: It's quite common to create questions using inflection..... of the voice. Hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are other ways of constructing questions. Many Australian languages use a verbal auxiliary which carries some modal meaning, to which they then attach subject and object agreement clitics. The Walmajarri language changes the auxiliary to create polar questions ([source](http://ausil.org.au/sites/ausil/files/WP-B-1%20Walmatjari%20-Part%202_0.pdf), p93):

```
yani  pa-lu    mangawarnti
went  AUX-3pl  girls
'The girls went.'

yani  nga-lu   mangawarnti
went  AUX-3pl  girls
'Did the girls go?'
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard Korean has an interrogative inflection (as opposed to declarative, imperative and propositive moods), as part of the property known as the ["pragmatic mood"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_verbs). It is characterised by -ㅂ니까 *-mnikka* for vowel stems or -습니까 *-seumnikka* for consonant stems in the formal polite level (as in 합니까 *hamnikka* and 있습니까 *issseumnikka*) and -느냐 *-neunya* for the formal plain level (하느냐 *haneunya* / 있느냐 *issneunya*). Adjectives (i.e. descriptive verbs) have a different inflection for the formal plain level: -냐 *-nya* for vowel stems and -으냐 *-eunya* for consonant stems. For all forms, this may be abbreviated to -니 *-ni* in speech.

There is generally no formal inflection distinction in the intimate (informal plain) [although many other interrogative forms are used, e.g. -지 *-ji*], the general polite (informal polite), the authoritative (semi-formal polite) and familiar (semi-formal, semi-polite).

Interestingly enough, the [Gyeongsang dialect group of Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyeongsang_dialect) (including Busan), in its informal plain layer, distinguishes between yes-no questions and wh-questions by inflection, with an -아 *-a* or -나 *-na* for yes-no questions and -오 *-o* or -노 *-no* for wh-questions.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese adds a particle "ma" to form polar questions from declaratives.

> You good 'you are good'
>   you good irr 'Are you good?'

Similarly, many Andean languages have clitics to form wh- and polar questions from declaratives and imperatives.

Comment: I'd like to see clarification / elaboration on the Andean claim. The "validation" suffix -chu in Quechua is also used to express doubt, so it is not a question marker, though it is used in questions.

Comment: Yes, -chu is conjectural in Quechua, not interrogative. Consider e.g. -cha, -sa and  -ti in Aymara: uka anu-wa 'that is a dog' but uka anu-ti 'is that a dog?'

Answer (score 0):

Japanese has a particle /ka/ <か> added to the end of the sentence that marks it as a question.

Declarative:
Anata wa nihonjin desu

Question: Anata wa nihonjin desu ka